# Is it correct to say "I choked on water through my nose"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

When swimming, water might get into your nose suddenly and cause a short sharp pain in your sinus and a short time of breathing difficulty.

We say "**he choked on water**" which implies the water went through the throat and it made you difficult to breathe for a short time.

Now we have a similar symptom. The water went through the nose and it made you difficult to breathe for a short time.

**Is it correct to say "I choked on water through my nose"?**

Comment: You're misunderstanding "choke". It means to suffocate or block. Whether it goes in through the mouth or the nose, water can't actually block the airways. But if water goes down the wrong way (through the *windpipe* to the lungs, rather than to the stomach), that causes a ***gag reflex***, which is sometimes loosely referred to as "choking". That's only really likely to happen with water you're deliberately trying to drink *through the mouth,* though. "Water mishaps" involving noses aren't very common, so the relevant vocabulary is limited. Mostly you'd just hear *"Water went/got up my nose!"*

Comment: Note that when you're drinking something (ie from a glass or cup) and it "goes the wrong way" and you starting coughing and spluttering you sometimes refer to that as **"aspirating"**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would not call this "choking".  I'd just say that "water went up my nose". I would also not call getting water in your throat as "choking". Perhaps "water inhalation", it is also called "[dry drowning](https://www.webmd.com/children/features/secondary-drowning-dry-drowning)".

Comment: This article says " The reason most swimmers choke on water is because they blow out all of their air too early or too late. The swimmer should breath to the side of the recovery arm (the arm which is out of the water) and take a big breath of air. " https://effortlessswimming.com/breathing-in-freestyle-how-to-stop-choking-on-water/#:~:text=The%20reason%20most%20swimmers%20choke,a%20big%20breath%20of%20air.

Comment: *I* would not call this choking.... but others might. But please see my article on "dry drowning"

Comment: I agree with "water went up my nose". But if (for example) you're drinking too fast and water goes down your into windpipe and you start coughing, that's known as choking in English. The key thing with choking is the involuntary coughing accompanied by an inability to breathe, no matter whether it's due to food or liquid.

Answer (score 0):

The other commentary aside, all of which I agree with, I will make a point: situation matters.

**If I was a lifeguard and I pulled someone out of the water who told me, "I choked on water through my nose,"** I would know *exactly* what they meant.

Just the same, if you had just come from the pool and you were hacking up phlegm and you told me that as an explanation, I would probably chuckle and, again, understand. Then I would feel sorry for you, and not because I think your English is poor.

It may not be perfectly correct. I can see at least a glimmer of correctness in it, if not more. It absolutely conveys the message clearly. The next best way to say this involves a truckload more words. In a traumatic situation, the brevity may even convey some humor or snark.